# 'REACT_APP_API_HOST' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: git, docker, powershell, plaid

Trying to set up a Docker image from the Plaid banking tutorial (https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/#introduction) but I am getting an error that I do not understand:

```
'REACT_APP_API_HOST' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

This the code being ran from Powershell:

```
git clone -c core.symlinks=true https://github.com/plaid/quickstart
cd quickstart

# Copy the .env.example file to .env, then fill out PLAID_CLIENT_ID and PLAID_SECRET in .env
cp .env.example .env

# start the container for one of these languages:
# node, python, java, ruby, or go
make up language=python
```

The makefile shows the following definition:

```
.PHONY: up
up:
    REACT_APP_API_HOST=http://$(language):8000 \
    $(DOCKER_COMPOSE) \
        $(DOCKER_COMPOSE_YML) \
        $@ --build --detach --remove-orphans \
        $(language)
    @echo $(SUCCESS_MESSAGE)
```

I have already had a few issues with the steps provided on their site and had to do a bit of messing around to get the 'make' command working but this part seems to be too generic to get me a response via Google search.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I took the liberty of changing "shell" tag to "powershell" as I believe this is powershell behavior you're experiencing.

Comment: @erik258 no problem, thanks

Comment: The error message implies that `cmd.exe` is interpreting your `up:` command, which cannot work, given that your command uses POSIX-compatible syntax (such as used by Bash).

Comment: The linked documentation states: "If you're using Windows, ensure you have a terminal capable of running basic Unix shell commands." Examples of that are Git Bash and WSL.